# C++ Template overriding rules

Tags: c++, templates, overriding

I'm trying to override a C++ template for a specific type, which implements a member function. It seems to me, that this is not possible with the current language spec.

Overriding just works, if I use specialization for one specific type.

The code always prints World instead of Hello.

Is there any way to tell the compiler to use the other template?

I cant modify the first template of serialize() because it is part of an external library. I can just add additional templates.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>

struct PanelBarcode
{
    std::string value;

    template<class S> void Serialize(S& in_s)
    {
        std::cout << value;
    }
};

template <typename Archive, typename C>
struct has_serialize
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr auto check(T*)
        -> typename
        std::is_same<
        decltype(std::declval<T>().Serialize(std::declval<Archive&>())),
        void
        >::type;

    template<typename>
    static constexpr std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
    static constexpr bool value = type::value;
};


struct X {
    X() {}
    template<class S> void Serialize(S& in_s)
    {  }
};



template<class A, class T>
void serialize(A ar, T& obj, const unsigned int version)
{
    std::cout << "World";
}

template<class A, class T, typename std::enable_if_t<has_serialize<A, T>::value> * = nullptr>
void serialize(A ar, T& obj, const unsigned int version)
{
    obj.Serialize(ar);
}

struct Y
{
    Y() {}
};

int main()
{
    PanelBarcode bc;
    bc.value = "Hello";

    Y y;

    serialize<Y, PanelBarcode>(y, bc, 13);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code above gives a compile error (ambigous), because the solution does not work. I need a working solution.

Comment: But your question says the code prints "World". Edit your question with the appropriate error message instead.

Comment: You can't modify the "world" version but you can play from the calling side? I mean: the third argument is an `unsigned int` but you call it with an `int`; if your serialize version accept an `int` as third parameter, and you ever call `serialize()` with an `int` as third argument, you can break the ambiguity.

Comment: Hi max66! Unfortunately I cant modify the calling side. If ithis would be possible, it would be easy to solve my problem.